# Can I embed a string resource into another string resource?

Tags: android, localization, kotlin, string.xml

The Code A is a string resource, I hope to merge two string resources into one, just like Code B, can I do it in Android Studio 3.01?
Now I have upgraded to kotlin.

**Code A**

```
<string name="app_name">Backup Settings</string>
<string name="FeedbackEmailSubject">Report bug and suggestion about Backup Settings</string>
```

**Code B**

```
<string name="app_name">Backup Settings</string>
<string name="FeedbackEmailSubject">Report bug and suggestion about <string name="app_name"/></string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is such a way. Best way right now is below.

```
<string name="app_name">Backup Settings</string>
<string name="FeedbackEmailSubject">Report bug and suggestion about %1$s</string>
```

Observe %1$s in second string and in Code you do

```
getString(R.string.FeedbackEmailSubject,getString(R.string.app_name))
```

Which should give you out put like

```
Report bug and suggestion about Backup Settings
```